# Google App Engine's blacklist not listing top IP addresses

Tags: g-suite, denial-of-service

I'm dealing with DOS attacks at the moment and could use a hand.

In the past, App Engine would show the top IP Addresses hitting an instance on https://appengine.google.com/blacklist, but it's not showing them anymore.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the top IP addresses on the [new admin console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Is there a way?

Comment: I appreciate the mystery down vote :-p  is this the wrong forum? Question is about Google App Engine System Maintenance - per the docs on google  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#blacklists  top ip addresses should be listed here: https://appengine.google.com/blacklist but mine is always empty - though i'm getting very high traffic.  I need to identify top IP clients on my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is a known issue, please see [GAE issue 11234](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11234).

Possible workarounds:

- [export GAE logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export) to BigQuery or Cloud Storage for outbound log processing and analysis
- push application usage information to Google Analytics via 
  [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)